# For which values the following summation converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

I have the following problem:

**For which $a$ and $b$ values does the following summation converges:**

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left(a-\frac{(n-b)^n}{n^n}\right)$$

I tried to solve this in many ways but keep failing since I don't know how to deal with this kind of questions especially with two parameters and not one.

Comment: Hi @smith_brown. It will be very useful to frame your questions using TeX, a tutorial for which is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @caffeinemachine Thanks, I did it!

Answer (score 0):

$a\ne 1$ the series terms $\to \pm (a-1)$ which won't converge.

For $a=1$, two cases:

(1) $b\ne 0$, the series is alternately decreasing,  so it converges (conditionally).

(2) $b=0$ all terms $=0$, so convergence is trivial.

Comment: why others say it's a=e^(-b) I got different answers here...

Comment: $a-e^{-b}$ is the limit of the sequence, not the series.  So $a=e^{-b}$ is necessary for convergence.  I believe they are right, so my answer should be disregarded.  Also the $(-1)^{n-1}$ allows for conditional convergence.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\frac{(n-b)^n}{n^n}=(1-\frac bn)^n$$

$$=e^{n\ln(1-\frac bn)}$$

$$e^{-b}(1-\frac{b^2}{2n})+\frac 1n\epsilon(n))$$
If the series converges, necessarily, its general term must go to zero.
thus, we must have
$$a=e^{-b}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=a-\left(1-\frac{b}{n}\right)^n$, then the series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}a_n$.

- You will need to have $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{b}{n}\right)^n=e^{-b}=a$
- Also try to show that for each $b\in \mathbb{R},$ $a_n>0$ and $(a_n)$ decreases monotonically from some index $N$, then convergence follows from the alternating series test.

Comment: I got the first one but could you explain the second?

Comment: @smith_brown See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test. If you can prove that $a_n>0$ from some index $N$ and $a_{n+1}<a_n$ (the sequence is decreasing), then the series converges by this test.

Comment: But it says: The alternating series test then says: if |an| decreases monotonically and a(n)------>0 then the alternating series converges. but that doesn't mean every alternating series does so

Comment: @smith_brown No, you need to prove that $(a_n)$ is decreasing from some index $N$. Or maybe there are other, easier methods to prove that it converges for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: why no, the page on wikipedia doesn't say that every alternating series should decreases monotonically

Comment: @smith_brown It only says that if the terms decrease monotonically and converge to 0, then this is a sufficient condition for the series to converge.

Comment: understood, could you help with proving that it decreases monotonically? I tried but it was too hard since sometimes n is even sometimes it's not...

Comment: It is sufficient to prove that $(1-b/n)^n$ is increasing for $n>|b|$ using Bernoulli's inequality (there may be proofs on the web) @smith_brown

Comment: But I can only use Bernoulli's inequality on one side... plus it's wrong to use Bernoulli's inequality when I'm looking on another inequality